# Is it OK to name an instance the same as a module?

Tags: python, namespaces, python-import

I often find it 'natural' to name both a module containing a class definition and instances of that class in lowercase, and to use camel-case for the class name. For example, I want to do this:

```
In [2]: from publisher import Publisher

In [3]: publisher = Publisher()
```

Here I have a module named `publisher`, but also an instance of `Publisher` called the same way. It seems like the module and the instance both 'work' as expected:

```
In [4]: from publisher import RandomData

In [5]: publisher.random.uuid()
Out[5]: 'c490508d-2071-536e-2f38-4b03b04351e1'
```

where I've imported another class from the module and called an instance method. Does Python 'understand from the context' whether I mean the module or the instance? Is it OK to re-use names in this way?

Comment: Not sure what you think might conflict here. Python is case-sensitive; `publisher` is different from `Publisher`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Kurt noticed that publisher is as well module as `Publisher`'s instance name.

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand now.

Comment: As you note, it "works", but is potentially confusing to readers of the code since after creating the instance `publisher`, the name now refers to two different things depending on context, so I suggest you avoid the ambiguity this practice creates (and it doesn't follow the PEP8 naming guidelines).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not shadowing anything, no name is being reused here. The name `publisher` was *not being used* in your namespace until you created that instance with `publisher = Publisher()`. If you tried to use the name `publisher` right after the `from publisher import Publisher` line, you'd get a `NameError` exception.

That's because the `from <module> import <name>` form only sets `<name>` in your namespace. It doesn't matter where `<name>` was imported from; at no point would you get a `<module>` name in your namespace.

Put differently, the `from publisher import Publisher` statement basically translates to:

```
if 'publisher' not in sys.modules:
    # find and load the publisher module
    # sys.modules['publisher'] = newly_loaded_module
Publisher = sys.modules['publisher'].Publisher  # set the Publisher global
```

except the name `sys` is never set in your namespace, Python just accesses `sys.modules` directly internally.

So, from a technical point of view: no, this is perfectly fine.

You *may* find that using the module name for the instance variable can create confusion as to what the name refers to *to a future reader of your code*, if not to Python.

You may also have gotten this confused with

```
import publisher
publisher = publisher.Publisher()
```

That could *would* shadow the module. The line `import publisher` sets the global name `publisher`, and on the next line you *replace* `publisher` with a new object reference.

Cast into the same `sys.modules` language, you'd be doing this:

```
if 'publisher' not in sys.modules:
    # find and load the publisher module
    # sys.modules['publisher'] = newly_loaded_module
publisher = sys.modules['publisher']  # set the publisher global
publisher = publisher.Publisher()     # set the publisher global to something else
```

That's fine too, *unless* you expect that `publisher.Publisher()` would work again later on. `publisher` no longer references the module, so that could cause issues. This is yet more confusing for human readers.

Comment: so if I call `publisher` I mean the module or the `Publisher`'s instance name?

Comment: @pt12lol: You never had a name `publisher` in your namespace before the `publisher = Publisher()` line. So `publisher`, once set, references the instance.

Comment: @pt12lol: you can try this out yourself. In a new Python interpreter session, use `from publisher import Publisher`, then `publisher` on a line by itself. You'll get a `NameError` exception. The name doesn't exist in your current namespace.

Comment: ah, ok, just read again the question. so what if we did `import publisher; publisher = publisher.Publisher()`? this looks completely unreadable, but I'm afraid it would work with `publisher` as an instance name...

Comment: @pt12lol: that would still work. Python would *first* bind `publisher` to the module object. It would then, in a next step, bind `publisher` to the instance.  You can then no longer use the name `publisher` to reference the module. Modules are just objects here; this is basically the same thing as `foo = 42` then `foo = 'bar'`.

Comment: yup, it is worth to add this to your answer

Comment: @pt12lol: however, that's not what you asked; you asked if `from publisher import Publisher` and `publisher = Publisher()` is fine. The form of the import statement is *important* there. What basically happens when you do `from publisher import Publisher` is `Publisher = sys.modules['publisher'].Publisher` (after Python first makes sure that `sys.modules['publisher']` has been loaded).

Comment: I just tried importing another class I added to the `publisher.py` module right after creating an instance of first class imported (`Publisher`) and naming it `publisher` and this worked fine, so your statement about getting a `NameError` exception in a case like that appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @martineau if you wrote `from publisher import OtherClass` it works fine, because python will look for the module named 'publisher' in its search paths, just like Martijn explained. It won't work if you try `import publisher.OtherClass`.

Comment: @martineau: if you use `from foo import bar`, the name `foo` is **not** set. You **will** get a `NameError` on that unless something *else* sets the name `foo`. See the [`import` statement reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) for all the ways an `import` statement will bind names. You didn't share your attempts, but if you did not get a `NameError` then *you* bound the name already somewhere.

Comment: My attempt that worked was `from publisher import Publisher`, `publisher = Publisher()`, `from publisher import AnotherClass`, `another = AnotherClass()` using Python 2.7.12.

Comment: @martineau: you have set `publisher` in that case. It is bound to an instance. So in that case there is no `NameError` because you set the name. I did classify when you'd see a `NameError`, namely **right after the first import**. So `from publisher import Publisher; print(publisher)`. I'm trying to show that the `from publisher import ..` statement did not bind the name `publisher`.

Comment: I know what my code is doing and understand why it works—nevertheless, I don't recommend the practice for the reasons stated in my comment under the OP's question. I just don't think that part of what you wrote in your answer is correct (or at best is unclear).

Comment: @martineau: what part of *If you tried to use the name `publisher` right after the `from publisher import Publisher` line* isn't clear?